# How do I create the following macro

Tags: math-mode, macros

[image]

How do I create this where `{a}{b}{c}` are variables for a possible math formula?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 11):

I suggest using the `amsmath` command `\genfrac` which will resize as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\test}[3]{\left( \genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\,\middle\vert\, #3\right)}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \test a b c
  \quad \scriptstyle \test{a}{b}{c}
  \quad \scriptscriptstyle \test{a}{b}{c}
\end{equation*}
\( \test a b c \)

\end{document}
```

`\genfrac` takes six arguments, the first two are delimiters around the "fraction", then next is the thickness of the horizontal dividing line, set to `0pt` here to make it invisible, and the last two are the numerator and denominator of the fraction.

If you want to have good control over the enclosing brackets `(...)` then an alternative definition can be given using the `mathtools` package:

[image: mathtools version]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\test}[3]{(}{)}{\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\,\delimsize\vert\, #3}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \test* a b c\quad \scriptstyle \test* a b c\quad
  \scriptscriptstyle \test* a b c
\end{equation*}
\( \test a b c \)

\begin{equation*}
  \test*{a^X}{b_Y}{c_Z} \quad \test[\Bigg]{a^X}{b_Y}{c_Z}
  \quad \test[\bigg]{a^X}{b_Y}{c_Z}
  \quad \test[\Big]{a^X}{b_Y}{c_Z}
  \quad \test[\big]{a^X}{b_Y}{c_Z}
  \quad \test{a^X}{b_Y}{c_Z}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

This time you have use `\test*` for the version with automatic sizing of brackets, `\test` just gives you ordinary brackets, but you also get the possiblities `\test[\big]`, `\test[\Big]` etc. where the brackets sizes are explicitly specified.

Comment: Be very careful about `\left` and `\right` when used in the text. Try `$ \text b g c $`, then the fences disturb the line spacing (add a line of text above and below). It is anoying to use, but `\mathchoice` might be a better choice.

Comment: @daleif You are perfectly correct about use inline in text.  I'll add an alternative mathtools macro to my answer.

Answer (score 9):

How about this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text            
\newcommand\test[3]{\text{voor }\left( \begin{array}{@{}c@{\,}} #1 \\ #2 \end{array}\middle|\ \ #3 \right)}
\begin{document}
\[                                           
\test{a}{b}{c}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't been able to figure out what this piece of code in your example does: \begin{array}{@{}c@{\,}}

Comment: @min it removes `column sep`